# Image position between inputs xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to put an image in the middle of two inputs, that means that I would like to have the same margin to the first input as the second input. I'm going to explain better with an example:

```
[input a]---- 20px-----[image]---- 20px-----[input b]
```

I want to have the image always at the middle between them, because when I rotate the screen I have to make it large.

I have to use constraints? Which one? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give some more details. What do you mean by inputs? Is it something entered by user dynamically? In what control do you want to achieve the mentioned layout i.e. in textField or a View?

Comment: When I say input I mean UITextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this. (There are a number of ways to approach everything, lol).

I'm only going to show AutoLayout solutions because it will make things easer when things are moving. Also, your description is pretty much already using AutoLayout Visual Format Language.

The first would be to place `inputA`, `inputB` and `image` into a third view which I'll call `interfaceView`.

Now you can lay it out like this...

```
|[inputA] // i.e. up against the left edge
[inputB]| // i.e. up against the right edge

[image] is different. You then align the centre of image with the centerX of interfaceView
```

The second option is to use "spacer" views.

Create two more views called `spacer1` and `spacer2` and layout the screen like this...

```
[inputA][spacer1][image][spacer2(==spacer1)][inputB]
```

Make spacer 1 and 2 hidden. They are just there for layout purposes. Now, because I have given them equal widths they will align the image view exactly in the middle of A and B.

Comment: Cool solution (the first one). I'm going to try that Fogmeister, I hope it works ;) Thanks!!